# How can I setup two step verification in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, multi-factor-auth

I read in the NYTimes that PayPal supports two-step verification, but I can't see where to set it up. How do I set up two-step verification in PayPal?

Answer (score 4):

It's done in your settings:

*Profile* → *My Settings* → *Security Key* → *Get Started* → **Get Security Key**

You can either pay for a physical token that will display your one-time password (OTP) key, or you can register a mobile phone, the instructions are right there.

Note: to register a phone it needs to be able to receive text messages, as that is how the OTP is sent.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have it yet on my account so here's how I did it. The correct name of the product is `Paypal Security Key`

- Log into [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com)
- Search for "Security Key"
- A result should be auto-suggested as you type

  [image]
- Click the suggested keyword
- On the resulting page click "Security Key" under the "Best Matches" section
- In the resulting text find the "get one today" link and click it
- choose from the following options

[image]

- I'm going with the Register your phone option for the rest of the steps
- Enter your phone number in each of the spaces provided. If you use google voice, enter your actual telephone number so that the shortcode message will get to you - because [PayPal does not accept Google Voice phone numbers](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/voice/OkHVPa2eBa0).

[image]

- The click "Agree and Register"

[image]

- Enter in the 6-digit code you receive on your phone

[image]

[image]

Enjoy your two-step authentication aka "Security Key"

Comment: I don't have any search bar in Paypal.  Does it have to be enabled?

Comment: it should be in the upper right of the page when you're logged in and on the dashboard.

Comment: Is this only for the US? I can not find anything similar in Paypal Spain.

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to activate this feature in The Netherlands. When clicking [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_security-key) on "Activate now" I get and error "The Security Key is currently not available." and demo link results HTTP 404.